# How do I tell my T2i to use a particular spot for AF reference?

Tags: canon, autofocus, focus-point-selection, fast-lenses

I just got a 50mm f/1.2 to go along with my T2i, but many of my photos are out of focus because the AF catches my subject's knee instead of her eyes, despite focusing on her eyes and recomposing.  What can I do to achieve a more precise/consistent autofocus, particularly in low-light situations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would I want to select an autofocus point?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/why-would-i-want-to-select-an-autofocus-point)

Comment: I don't know if this is a duplicate — that covers _why_, but this seems to be just plain a _how to do it_ question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting the autofocus point is covered on [page 68 of the manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0300004289/02/eosrt2i-eos550d-im3-c-en.pdf)<sup>1</sup>:

> Selecting the AF point
>
> [...]
>
> 1. Press the [AF point selection] button
>
> [...]
>
> 2. Select the AF point
>
> Press the [4 way controller] to select the AF point
>   While looking in the viewfinder, you can select the AF point by turning the [main command dial] until the desired AF point lights in red.

The "AF point selection" button is the one at the top-right of the back plate of the camera, which you also use to zoom *in* during image replay.

1. Strictly, that link is to the 550D (European version) rather than the T2i (American version) manual. However, there's no functional difference between the cameras, but the information may be on a slightly different page.